# Spring MVC RequestMapping Trailing Double Slash Issues

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml, servlet-mapping

So I am having an issue with this URL: http://example.com/something//?filter=something (notice the double trailing slash)

I have a controller set up to handle "/something" as the request mapping, but when there are double trailing slashes, the request mapping goes to "/" instead of "/something".

In my web.xml file, I have a servlet-mapping with the URL pattern of "/".

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fe</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html. I noticed that their example has a url-pattern of "/*" unlike mine "/".

I changed my url-pattern to "/*" and everything works correctly with the only issue being now you can add however many trailing slashes as you want.

What do you think the problem is and do you think changed the url-pattern to "/*" will fix the problem or am I not looking in the right place for the issue? Thanks in advance. :)

Edit: (adding controller per request)

```
@Controller public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/"
    )
    public ModelAndView displayIndex() {
        // do things
    }

    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/something"
    )
    public ModelAndView displaySomething() {
        // do things
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: @minion controller now posted above

Comment: @TimKipp can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?  I dont understand why you would want any trailing slashes to begin with!

Comment: @ConMan I don't intend to have the trailing slashes there, but it is a bug I found if they are added and want to know how to fix it from breaking in this way.